# Understanding the proof of Theorem 2.6. Hungerford's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

The following is from Hungerford's book of Algebra :

[image]

I can understand all but the two parts that I have highlighted. Detailed simple explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 0):

Let us prove in detail the two parts:

**Part 1**: Let us show that $f^{-1}(T)$ is a finite subset of $X$ for every $T \in Im(f) \subset K(Y)$.

Given any $T \in Im(f) \subset K(Y)$, note that  each $y\in T$ is a linear combination of a finite subset $G_y$ of $X$. Let us define $S= \bigcup_{y\in T} G_y \subset X$. Since $T$ is finite, $S$ is finite. Note that any element $y \in T$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $S$

Now, given any $x \in f^{-1}(T)$, then $x$ can written as a linear combination of elements in $T$, and so $x$ can written as a linear combination of elements in $S$. Since $x \in X$ and $S \subset X$, and $X$ is linearly independent, we must have $x \in S$. So, for all  $x \in f^{-1}(T)$,  $x \in S$, that is $f^{-1}(T) \subset S$. Therefore $f^{-1}(T)$ is finite.

**Part 2**: Let us prove that $\{f^{-1}(T):  T \in Im(f) \}$ is a partition of $X$.

1. For every $x \in X$,  $f(x) \in K(Y)$. So, there is $T \in Im(f)$ such that $x \in f^{-1}(T)$.
2. Let $T_1, T_2 \in Im(f)$ such that $T_1\neq T_2$, then  $T_1=\{y_{1}, \dots y_k\} \subseteq Y$ and  $T_2=\{y'_{1}, \dots y'_t\} \subseteq Y$ and, we may assume without loss of generality, that $y_1 \notin T_2$.

Now, suppose $f^{-1}(T_1)$ and $f^{-1}(T_2)$ have a non-empty intersection, then there is $x \in f^{-1}(T_1) \cap f^{-1}(T_2)$.  It means that we have

$$ x= r_1 y_1 + \dots + r_k y_k $$
and
$$ x= s_1y'_1 + \dots + s_t y'_k $$

where all  $r_i$ and all $s_j$  are different than $0$.

So, $Y$ is a linearly independent and $x$ can be written in two different ways as a linear combination of elements in $Y$. Contradiction. So , $f^{-1}(T_1)$ and $f^{-1}(T_2)$ are disjoint.

So, $\{f^{-1}(T):  T\in Im(f) \}$ is a partition of $X$.